# AWSCloudFormation - cfn-init failed to run command `ruby`

Tags: ruby, bootstrapping, aws-cloudformation

I have a simple cloudformation script where I am trying to run a ruby script as a background process at boot-time.

The relevant section of the script is

```
"AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
                    "config" : {
                        "sources" : {
                            "/etc/scripts" : "http://bootstrap-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com/scripts.zip"
                        },
                        "commands" : {
                          "1" : {
                            "command" : "cd /etc/scripts/agent"
                          },
                          "2-start" : {
                            "command" : "nohup ruby agent.rb &"
                          }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Just to confirm that the zip file is downloaded and the scripts are present in the correct directory. Also my AMI has **ruby 2.0.0** installed for all users.

I keep on getting `nohup: failed to run command 'ruby': No such file or directory`
 in the **\var\log\cfn-init.log** file

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

AWS::CloudFormation::Init is run by default as a root user during stack creation or update actions. It's possible the bin directory containing ruby 2.0(is usually the case in AMI's shipped by amazon) isn't sourced in PATH, or use the full location of ruby for example /usr/local/bin/ruby.

Comment: I have manually tried logging on the instance later and switching to the root user. The scripts run fine which indicates that there is some other problem..

Answer (score 1):

The issue is a result of the commands being executed in isolation.  Your first command is changing directories, but this has no bearing on your second command.  The solution is to use the 'cwd' key for the second command.  For example:

```
"AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
                    "config" : {
                        "sources" : {
                            "/etc/scripts" : "http://bootstrap-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com/scripts.zip"
                        },
                        "commands" : {
                          "2-start" : {
                            "command" : "nohup ruby agent.rb &",
                            "cwd" : "/etc/scripts/agent"
                          }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

More information: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html#aws-resource-init-commands

Comment: This saved my life, was banging my head against the well forever!  Thank you.  One thing though, about nohup in cfn-init:  The "command success" message never seems to show up in the cfg-init.log - just stops at "running/no test..".  The command seems to run (my app is running)...but I'm wondering if cfg-init is completed and just hanging forever.  Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: did you ever figure out the issue with nohup in cfn-init ?  I am experiencing a similar problem with the hang, and the next command never runs